.NET 7 AES Decryption throws Padding is invalid and cannot be removed error
I am trying to do some (basic?) AES encryption with a variable IV but get garbage back and if the string to be encrypted is too short I get 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed'. I am including the IV in the encrypted value for randomness and then removing it before decrypting the remaining value.
 public class AesEncryption
 {
    private static byte[] key = new byte[32] { some key }; // 256-bit key
    public static string Encrypt(string plaintext)
    {
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            var iv = aesAlg.IV;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
            byte[] encryptedBytes;
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(plaintext);
                    }
                }
                encryptedBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
            return new AesCbcCiphertext(iv, encryptedBytes).ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string ciphertext)
    {
    var cbcCiphertext = AesCbcCiphertext.FromBase64String(ciphertext);
    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, aesAlg.IV);
        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cbcCiphertext.CiphertextBytes))
        {
            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                { 
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



internal class AesCbcCiphertext
{
    public byte[] IV { get; }
    public byte[] CiphertextBytes { get; }

    public static AesCbcCiphertext FromBase64String(string data)
    {
        var dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        return new AesCbcCiphertext(
        dataBytes.Take(16).ToArray(),
        dataBytes.Skip(16).ToArray()
        );
    }

    public AesCbcCiphertext(byte[] iv, byte[] ciphertextBytes)
    {
        IV = iv;
        CiphertextBytes = ciphertextBytes;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var total = IV.Concat(CiphertextBytes).ToArray();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(IV.Concat(CiphertextBytes).ToArray());
    }
}

I think I have read every post on Stack related to it and have tweaked the decryption in various ways with no luck. Interestingly if I use the same hardcoded IV it works. I thought the IV didn't matter for decryption?

The IV does matter for decryption; you must use the same IV for decryption that you used for encryption. You do prepend the IV to the ciphertext, but for decryption you then ignore that IV and use whatever default IV is generated by Aes.Create(). Though if you have more than one block of ciphertext that mistake should not cause the error you received. As usual, a [mre] example would go a long way to isolating the cause.

Is there a way to guarantee at least 2 blocks of ciphertext?

This is a minimal reproducible example. Just run var encrypted = AesEncryption.Encrypt("ABCD1234567"); var decrypt = AesEncryption.Decrypt(encrypted);

key size = (128 or 256) and  block size = (128)

You must set KeySize, BlockSize, Key, IV, Padding, Mode on both sides to the same value before the encrypt/decrypt process occurs.

You can use KeySize = 128 or KeySize = 256 on both sides but they must be the same KeySize.

You must use BlockSize = 128 on both sides, and cannot use BlockSize = 256.

When you call Aes.Create() in both processes (encrypt/decrypt) then Aes will automatically generate 2 different Key and generate 2 different IV.

You are using the same Key in both processes (this is correct), but with different IV in both processes (this is your a problem).

So turns out you do need to use the original IV when decrypting—and since I am storing it as part of the ciphertext, I can use it when decrypting.
Change this line in the decrypt:
ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, aesAlg.IV);

To:
ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, cbcCiphertext.IV);

Now, cbcCiphertext.IV Is being parsed from the encrypted value.

Anyone that you allow to decrypt your data must possess the same key and IV and use the same algorithm.

Sending the Key and IV across an insecure network without encryption is unsafe because anyone who intercepts the Key and IV can then decrypt your data. To communicate a symmetric key and IV to a remote party, you usually encrypt the symmetric Key and IV by using asymmetric encryption.

The key is not sent anywhere.
